# Update css with jquery in ajax?

Tags: html, css, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to update the css (the css is located in my main.css) of divs that do not exist on my main html file but do in the files i am injecting. Is this possible? if so how?

ok so here is what I have in my main html file

```
<div id="container">
<div id="page">
    <!placeholder>
</div></div>
```

sorry about the bad formatting i just can't get the tabs and new lines to work with the code input system on this site.

next is what I have for main.css

```
#container {
position: fixed;
margin-right: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;}
#page {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 1600px;
z-index: 10;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;}
#recposts {
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:1200px;}
.child {
height: 400px;
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
z-index: 11;
background-color: #EDEDED;
width: 100%;
padding-right: 10px;}
```

alright and now what I'm injecting

```
<div id ="page">    
<div id="recposts" class="child">
    <h1> Recent Posts  </h1> 
</div></div>
```

So I need to be able to edit the position top of #recposts and the height of .child.

I fixed my issue the problem was that I wasn't editing the css on the html load. I put the function into the .load() and now it works.

Comment: How are you injecting these new files?

Comment: You should edit your question and post what code you are injecting and what style you expect to be applied.

Comment: alright I edited it, hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, from what I understood, you can solve it using Jquery live() api.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

You can change whatever you want to the newly added items by using Jquery live() api.

You can trigger a function call after insertion, by using jquery's DOM change() api .
http://api.jquery.com/change/

eg :

```
$('#container').change(function() {
  $('#page').css("height",200);
});
```

EDIT: Since the change() api will not work on divs, here's the correct version

```
$('#container').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  $('#page').css("height",200);
});
```

Comment: The `.change` event is only available for certain form elements, so that part of your answer would not work.

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS rules are in a file that is already loaded (your `main.css`), then any new elements that are added later (say, from whatever HTML you're talking about injecting), and that match selectors in the CSS file, will automatically have the styling rules applied. Is that what you're after?

Comment: yeah that's what I thought but I want to edit the css with jquery before that html is injected

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for, but this will add a span with class "someClass" to the div id="insertion".

css:

```
.someClass{ background-color:black; }
```

html:

```
<div id="insertion"></div>
```

js:

```
<script>
 var toInsert = document.createElement("span");
 toInsert.className = "someClass";
 document.getElementById("insertion").append(toInsert);
</script>
```